# Regex - Substring based on condition

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex expression to use it in C#

The use of the regex is to get a substring of the input according to the input size

**The regex expression target**

If the input size less than 13 then get the full input

Else if the input size is greater than 25 then get from the input the substring from index 3 till index 16 (so that I skip the first three chars)

Here is what I came with till now

```
(?(?=.{25,}).{3}(.{13})|(?(?=.{0,13})(.{0,13})))
```

This is not working since when the input size is greater than 25 the result is not trimming the first three chars

Check it [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%28%3F%3D.%7B25%2C%7D%29.%7B3%7D%28.%7B13%7D%29%7C%28%3F%28%3F%3D.%7B0%2C13%7D%29%28.%7B0%2C13%7D%29%29%29&i=12345678901234567890123456780)

Comment: Why regex? Can't you just use simple if with substring?

Comment: You are not getting anything for sizes between 14 and 25?

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes true

Comment: Try [`^(?=.{25,}).{3}(?<res>.{13})|^(?=.{0,13}$)(?<res>.*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.%7b25%2c%7d%29.%7b3%7d%28%3f%3cres%3e.%7b13%7d%29%7c%5e%28%3f%3d.%7b0%2c13%7d%24%29%28%3f%3cres%3e.*%29&i=1234567890123456789012345), the result is  in Group "res".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't work

Comment: @MohammadHamoud It does, see my link, check *Table* tab.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is not skipping the first three chars when the length more than 25

Comment: @MohammadHamoud What do you mean? They are not captured in Group "res". What are you doing? Please describe your problem in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166529/discussion-between-mohammad-hamoud-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a non-regex solution is rather trivial:

```
public string check(string s)
{
    var res = "";
    if (s.Length>=25)
        res = s.Substring(3,13);
    else if (s.Length <= 13)
        res = s;
    return res;
}
```

If you want to use a regex, you may use

```
^(?=.{25,}).{3}(?<res>.{13})|^(?=.{0,13}$)(?<res>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3D.%7B25%2C%7D%29.%7B3%7D%28%3F%3Cres%3E.%7B13%7D%29%7C%5E%28%3F%3D.%7B0%2C13%7D%24%29%28%3F%3Cres%3E.*%29&i=1234567890123456789012345). Compile with `RegexOptions.Singleline` to support newlines in the input.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{25,})` - if there are 25 or more chars after the start of string, match
- `.{3}` - any 3 chars
- `(?<res>.{13})` - and capture 13 chars into `res` group
- `|` - or
- `^(?=.{0,13}$)` -  make sure there are no more than 0 to 13 chars in the string and then
- `(?<res>.*)` - grab the whole string (if no `RegexOptions.Singleline` is used, only 1 line will be matched).

Use it as

```
var res = "";
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^(?=.{25,}).{3}(?<res>.{13})|^(?=.{0,13}$)(?<res>.*)")
if (m.Success) 
{
    res = m.Groups["res"].Value;
}
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/MAqnk7).